# Derrida-Searle debate - any information?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, analytic-philosophy, continental-philosophy

I would like to know how Derrida-Searle debate went on (Wikipedia is lacking, and Searle's response is somehow difficult to find.).

Can anyone provide me some summary and some crucial details?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Derrida volume *[Limited, Inc.](http://users.clas.ufl.edu/burt/inc.pdf)* contains the critical documents, minus Searle's piece, due to Searle's refusing permission.

The publications went like this:

Derrida, in 1971, delivered a lecture in Montreal entitled "[Signature Event Context](https://advancedhermeneutics.wikispaces.com/file/view/Derrida+Signature+Event+Context.pdf)", which discussed the notion of communication in various philosophers from Condillac to Austin.   This work was published in the journal *Glyph*, and in Derrida's 1972 collection *Margins of Philosophy*.

In 1977, Searle published a reply to Derrida entitled "[Reply to Derrida: Reiterating the Differences](https://spat2013.wikispaces.com/file/view/29238861-Reiterating-the-Differences-A-Reply-to-Derrida-by-John-R-Searle.pdf)", also in *Glyph*.  Searle seem to be suffering under the illusion that Derrida was somehow attacking Austin, and rushed to defend Austin from Derrida's alleged attack.  Unfortunately for Searle, this was based upon a misreading of Derrida.  Ironically, one of the key points in Derrida's original piece was the *necessarily possibility* of such misreadings-- that one can never be sure one's intended message (to the extent that one can determine it) can successfully reach its destination.

In the same 1977 issue of *Glyph*, Derrida published a reply to Searle's reply, entitled "[Limited Inc a b c....](http://users.clas.ufl.edu/burt/inc.pdf)" (pg. 29) which playfully took apart Searle's misreading; it also quoted the entirety of Searle's piece within its own text (in fragments), in order to reiterate one of Derrida's other points in his original piece, concerning citationality (that texts can always be taken out of context, and placed in another context outside of the author's control.)

In 1988, Derrida collected his original essay and his response to Searle in the aforementioned volume *Limited Inc*; Searle declined to allow his piece to be reprinted, so the editors substituted a brief *précis* of Searle's argument.  In addition, Derrida appended an interview performed for the occasion in which he discusses the "debate" between himself and Searle entitled "Afterword: Toward an Ethic of Discussion" in which (among other things) he suggests that there is an ethical directive that one actually *read* and engage with the work one is attempting to critique, and that Searle failed this.

Comment: It seems that you are saying Derrida won the debate... Just saying, nothing else.

Comment: I'm saying the debate never took place; for there to be a debate, the two sides have to engage with each other.  Searle attacked an imagined foe who bore little resemblance to what Derrida actually wrote.  It was like Clint Eastwood debating an empty chair.

Comment: Is there any reading of Derrida which wouldn't count as a _misreading_?

Comment: "[L]et it be said in passing how surprised I have often
been, how amused or discouraged, depending on my humor, by
the user or abuse of the following argument: Since the
deconstructionist (which is to say, isn't it, the
skeptical-relativist-nihilist!) is supposed to not believe
in truth, stability, or the unity of meaning, in intention
or "meaning-to-say," how can he demand of us now that we
read *him* with pertinence, precision, rigor?   How can he
demand that his own text be interpreted correctly?  How can
he accuse anyone else of having misunderstood, simplified,
deformed it, etc.?  [cont]

Comment: In other words, how can he discuss, and
discuss the reading of what he writes?  The answer is simple
enough: This definition of the deconstructionist is *false*
(that's right: false, not true) and feeble; it supposes a
bad (that's right: bad, not good) and feeble reading of
numerous texts, first of all mine, which therefore must
finally be read or reread. Then perhaps it wil be
understood that the value of truth (and all those values
associated with it) is never contested or destroyed in my
writings, but only reinscribed in more powerful, larger,
more stratified contexts. [cont]

Comment: And that within interpretive
contexts (that is, within relations of force that are always
differential-- for example, socio-political-institutional--but
even beyond those determinations) that are relatively stable,
sometimes apparently almost unshakeable, it should be possible to
invoke rules of competence, criteria of discussion and of
consensus, good faith, lucidity, rigor, criticism, and
pedagogy." --Jacques Derrida, "Toward an Ethics of Discussion"

Comment: @Dennis - Is any reading of any text, be it authored by Derrida or Aristotle, that is not a misreading?

Comment: "In the eyes of philosophers, and certainly among those working in leading departments of philosophy throughout the world, M. Derrida's work does not meet accepted standards of clarity and rigour ... where coherent assertions are being made at all, these are either false or trivial." May 9, 1992. [A letter from Professor Barry Smith and others](http://ontology.buffalo.edu/smith/varia/Derrida_Letter.htm)

Answer (score 6):

All I have to contribute is that if you're still having trouble finding it, Searle's response has been made available on Scribd:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/29238861/Reiterating-the-Differences-A-Reply-to-Derrida-by-John-R-Searle

Comment: Also available [here](https://spat2013.wikispaces.com/file/view/29238861-Reiterating-the-Differences-A-Reply-to-Derrida-by-John-R-Searle.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I realize that I'm quite late to this discussion, but I just recently discovered a piece by Searle, The World Turned Upside Down, which appeared in the New York Review of Books in 1983 as a review of Jonathan Culler's "On Deconstruction" -- http://www.nybooks.com/articles/archives/1983/oct/27/the-word-turned-upside-down/

Comment: For those not subscribed to NYRB, Searle's entire review is available [here](http://free--expression.blogspot.com/2007/10/john-searle-on-derrida.html), and the resulting exchange is available [here](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/1984/02/02/an-exchange-on-deconstruction/).